# Building C++ static library to .a file for iOS. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "std::__1::__vector_base_common:: ..."

Tags: xcode, stdvector, armv7, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to build a .a file to include in a unity3d asset in order to let people build for iOS.
I get the following error when I try to build a game. (The error is a lot longer than this but it seems to be an issue with std::vector )

Building .a file for iOS. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "std::__1::__vector_base_common:: ..."

I saw [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/141) Someon has the same error and the solution is .. "add the -lc++ linker flag to your target's Build Settings"

I've tried this fix in the poroject from which I build the .a file from. When I try to build the library I get this error

Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lC++
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lC++ is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Note: I'm very inexperienced with osx and xcode.